# Python Pandas - How to iterate every N rows until end of dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I iterate 100 rows at a time in a Pandas dataframe? The forex_python package seems to error out when applying the lambda function all at once.

Here is what I've tried that doesn't seem to be working:

```
import pandas as pd
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
c = CurrencyRates()
row_processed = 0

for row in df.iterrows():
    try:
        df['USD_rate'] = df.apply(lambda x: c.get_rate(x['Currency'],'USD', x['Date']), axis = 1)
        row_processed += 1
        if row_processed == 100:
            row_processed = 0
            time.sleep(5)
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: Iterating  a dataframe is the last thing you want to do. Maybe give a sample of what you have and the expected output and see if the forum can suggest an alternative

Comment: Is it a download quota that's limiting you?  As in, whatever service is used under the hood to retrieve the data is not happy with the volume of requests?  In which case speed is unwanted (hence the sleep call)

Comment: @Riley Yes - it appears the volume of requests is causing it to error. And yes - that is why the sleep call exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

Get your currency base and dates in a list.

```
currencies = ['USD', 'GBP']
dates = pd.date_range(start='2021-06-01', periods=2)

# collect the dataframes
df_hold = []

for currency in currencies:
    for d in dates:
        try:
            url = 'https://theforexapi.com/api/{}/?base={}'.format(d, currency)
            r = requests.get(url).json()
            df_hold.append(pd.DataFrame(r))
        except:
            continue

# concat dataframe
pd.concat(df_hold)

           date base  rates
AUD  2021-06-01  USD  1.292
BGN  2021-06-01  USD  1.600
BRL  2021-06-01  USD  5.202
CAD  2021-06-01  USD  1.203
CHF  2021-06-01  USD  0.899
..          ...  ...    ...
SGD  2021-06-02  GBP  1.873
THB  2021-06-02  GBP 44.074
TRY  2021-06-02  GBP 12.150
USD  2021-06-02  GBP  1.415
ZAR  2021-06-02  GBP 19.422

[124 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: What is this code returning? A dictionary of dictionary? I'm trying to figure out how to put the output of your code into a dataframe.

Comment: updated my answer. let me know if it works. if you need to, you can add a sleep step as you iterate through the currencies and dates.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I also researched and found out that one can easily transform a json into pandas dataframe by using df = pd.json_normalize(r)

Answer (score 1):

In case I understood you correctly, you want to operate over `100` rows at a time then sleep for `5` sec and continue again. Here is how you can do it:

```
from forex_python.converter import CurrencyRates
c = CurrencyRates()
for g_name, df_group in df.groupby(df.index//100):
    try:
        condition = df.index.isin(df_group.index)
        df['USD_rate'] = np.where(condition, df_group.apply(lambda x: c.get_rate(x['Currency'], x['Date']), axis = 1), np.nan)
        time.sleep(5)
    except:
        continue
```

Comment: This technically works, however, your code still provides me the error "Currency Rates Source Not Ready" - it's probably not your code, but perhaps the API or the package's issue. I even upped the time.sleep to 10